# Can't click on webpage element using python selenium when used with mobile user-agent

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, user-agent

I am trying to automate clicking on the play button of an embedded iframe music player on a webpage, I am coding using python 3 and Selenium to select the element to click.

When the user-agent is changed to replicate a mobile device, a wrapper layer then obscures the button that I can normally click, it asks if I want to listen on the main site or in the browser. I want to listen in the browser, but so far everything I have tried to click the correct element to achieve that, has failed.

I believe I am clicking on the wrong part but cannot find a way to access the correct part.

The inspect window of the browser shows the below for the part of the wrapper I need to click on:

```
<a class="mobilePrestitial__link sc-font-light" href="#">
    Listen in browser
  </a>
  ::before
"
    Listen in browser
    "
    /a>
```

When I hover over the ::before part it highlights the part in the browser that I believe I need to click, but using right-click to inspect ::before just says 'scroll in view' so I cannot copy whatever the element represents.

My current code is this:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Listen in browser'))          
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="mobilePrestitial__link"]'))
)
element.click()
```

But it errors without a message, I suspect I need to be clicking on the element presented by ::before but cannot figure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround and solved this by hiding the wrapper overlay using Selenium in python script to make a Javascript call

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("mobilePrestitial")[0].style.display=\"none\"')
```

once the overlay is hidden with the above code, the original button is accessible in the browser